# Definite integral with change of limits

Tags: functions, definite-integrals, periodic-functions

If a function is defined such as $f(x+k)=f(x)$ for $k∈\mathbb{Z}^+ $(positive integer) and $\int\limits_{0}^{k} f(x) dx=I$. Then find $\int\limits_{0}^{k^2-k} f(x) dx$ in terms of $k$ and $I$.

Comment: What have you tried?  You know that $f(x)$ is periodic, which means that it repeats itself every $k$.  So, the integral of $f$ over two periods should be twice the integral of $f$ over one period (from the same lower limit).

Comment: Yeah I couldn't figure that out...now that I know the solution it seems like a stupid question to ask

Answer (score 2):

$f(x+k)=f(x)$ means $f$ is periodic with period $k$

so given

$I=\int_0^kf(x)dx$

$2I=\int_0^{2k}f(x)dx=\int_0^kf(x)dx+\int_k^{2k}f(x)dx$

Then

$$\int_0^{k(k-1)}f(x)dx=\int_0^{k}f(x)dx+\int_k^{2k}f(x)dx+...+\int_{k(k-2)}^{k(k-1)}f(x)dx=(k-1)I$$

Comment: Thanks for answering

Comment: Sure thing, I hope that made sense. Ask if you have more questions